# Operation on dynamic list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am not able to click on desired list element on a dynamic list.
The below picture is the screen print of the list populated by searching keyword "auto".

I want to select  *Automobile, Bus or Truck Parts Mfg. - Passenger Restraining Devices* this from the list.

below is my JS code which is causing error.

```
  var PrimaryClass="Automobile, Bus and Truck Body Manufacturing";
var stringClass=document.getElementsByTagName("div").class="x-combo-list-item";
 for (var i = 0; i < stringClass.length; i++)
 if( PrimaryClass==stringClass[i].innertext.contains(PrimaryClass))
{
stringClass[i].click();
}
```

Could anyone please help me to create a generic JS function for such element selection?[image]

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection use `[]` to access individual elemsnts

Comment: It's `innerText`, and there is no `contains` function in javascript. Use `indexOf >= 0`. And what is this: `.class="x-combo-list-item"`? You want to use `document.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item");` instead? Remove `PrimaryClass==` also in the `if`-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know where you're going with this, but this is how i would write it:

```
var primaryClass = "Automobile, Bus and Truck Body Manufacturing";
var stringClass = document.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item");
for (var i = 0; i < stringClass.length; i++){
    if (stringClass[i].innerText.indexOf(primaryClass) >= 0) {
        stringClass[i].click();
    }
}
```